# How can I repair a vinyl window that is not staying up?

Tags: repair, windows

I moved into a house.  There is one vinyl window with a problem.  If you unlatch the window, the top half drops like a guillotine.  Smash.  I'm surprised it isn't broken yet.  None of the other windows in the house do this.

I don't see any place where there would be a spring or counter-balance mechanism.  Do I just need to get the whole thing replaced, or is there a way to take this apart?  If I can DiY this thing, then how would I service it and where would I find parts (usually without knowing the part names, every web search seems to take you to Microsoft's web site... for windows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many single and double-hung vinyl windows have "spiral sash balances". An internet search of that term will reveal a lot of info. They are replaceable but it is not simple, and finding the right size can be a challenge also. If the windows are old consider a DIY replacement of the entire window unit with an easily installed block frame replacement window.

[image][image]